# Can't install release version of 'ms-vscode.remote-explorer' extension because it has no release version

Tags: vscode-extensions, devcontainer

I'm trying to install the extension pack for devcontainer development called "Remote Development", ms-vscode-remote.vscode-remote-extension pack.   I get the following message:

> [Window Title]
> Visual Studio Code
>
> [Content]
> Can't install release version of 'ms-vscode.remote-explorer' extension because it has no release version.
>
> [OK]

How can I resolve this?

## Environment

- Windows 11
- VSCode 1.72.1
- Docker Desktop 4.12.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of October 21st, 2022, The only version available for Remote Explorer is the pre-release version. I successfully installed this extension by manually installing the latest pre-release version of Remote Explorer instead.

You can do so by clicking on the downward-facing arrow on the "Install" button and then clicking on "Install Pre-Release Version.

[image: Installing Pre-Release Version of Remote Explorer]